# How to showing namespaces inside xml with xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my new (edited) more complete scenario:
I got a xml, that will transform with xsl. I got an example from the customer, that looks like:
XML that is infile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsi:myCompanyImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tns:myCompanyHeader xmlns:tns="http://www.MyComp.se/myCompany">
    <tns:sentFr>123456</tns:sentFr>
  </tns:myCompanyHeader>
  <tns:myCompanyUsers xmlns:tns="http://www.MyComp.se/myCompany">
    <tns:myCompanyUser ssn="1234567890">
      <tns:firstName>John</tns:firstName>
    </tns:myCompanyUser>
  </tns:myCompanyUsers>
</xsi:myCompanyImport>
```

XSL-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:tns="http://www.MyComp.se/myCompany"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.MyComp.se/myCompany myCompanyUsers.xsd"
                                xmlns:local="urn:cs">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="xsi:myCompanyImport" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <!--Start Header-->
            <xsl:element name="tns:myCompanyHeader" >
                <xsl:element name="tns:sentFr" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="_x0023_MyComp_header/@SentFrom" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <!--End Header-->

            <!--Start Users-->
            <xsl:element name="tns:myCompanyUsers">
                <!--Loop through persons-->
                <xsl:for-each select="_x0023_MyComp_header/_x0023_MyComp_Employee">
                    <xsl:element name="tns:myCompanyUser" >
                        <xsl:attribute name="ssn">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@inSsn" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:element name="tns:firstName" >
                            <xsl:value-of select="@inFname"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <!--End Loop-->
            </xsl:element>
            <!--End Users-->

        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Nevermind about the Csharp-code in the xsl, it's used for purposes not shown here.)
So, the result is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsi:myCompanyImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tns:myCompanyHeader xmlns:tns="http://www.MyComp.se/myCompany">
    <tns:sentFr>123456</tns:sentFr>
  </tns:myCompanyHeader>
  <tns:myCompanyUsers xmlns:tns="http://www.MyComp.se/myCompany">
    <tns:myCompanyUser ssn="1234567890">
      <tns:firstName>John</tns:firstName>
    </tns:myCompanyUser>
  </tns:myCompanyUsers>
</xsi:myCompanyImport>
```

But the customer wants:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsi:myCompanyImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tns:myCompanyHeader xmlns:tns="http://www.MyComp.se/myCompany">
    <tns:sentFr>123456</tns:sentFr>
  </tns:myCompanyHeader>
  <tns:myCompanyUsers xmlns:tns="http://www.MyComp.se/myCompany"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.maxm.se/myCompany myCompanyUsers.xsd">
    <tns:myCompanyUser ssn="1234567890">
      <tns:firstName>John</tns:firstName>
    </tns:myCompanyUser>
  </tns:myCompanyUsers>
</xsi:myCompanyImport>
```

How can I write this in the xsl so that shows up in the xml? I've tried many different ways, but with no success. It's actually just those 2 lines I would add to tns:myCompanyUsers:

```
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.maxm.se/myCompany myCompanyUsers.xsd">
```

I want in. But no success!

Comment: Are you sure the user data is in the xsi namespace? That's totally bizarre. But it's hard to help you more, I can't see what you want the output of your transformation to be.

Comment: Ehm. Well, they have changed their demands several time, and every time we talk to them I get new information. I will put a more complete scenario in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I write this in the xsl so that shows up in the xml?

Write it literally, i.e. instead of

```
<xsl:element name="myns:myCustomerUsers" >
```

use

```
<myns:myCustomerUsers xmlns:tns="http://www.myCustomerWeb.se/myCustomer" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myCustomerWeb.se/myCustomer myexuser.xsd">
```

or simply as

```
<myns:myCustomerUsers 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myCustomerWeb.se/myCustomer myexuser.xsd">
```

because literal result elements inherit the namespace nodes that were in scope at that point in the stylesheet (in your case, those declared on the `<xsl:stylesheet>`).  You probably need to add `exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"` to your `<xsl:stylesheet>` element, otherwise the `myns:myCustomerUsers` element will also get an `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` declaration.

You only need to use `<xsl:element>` when the element name is not a constant.

Comment: @user2497316 the same advice applies - if you have a specific element with a fixed name that you want to include in the output then just put it in the style sheet as a literal element, you don't need `<xsl:element>` unless you want to build the element's name dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your first answer properly. Of course you are right, I wrote it as-is in the tag, and violá!

Thanks alot.

J